# AASM callbacks not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using AASM to manage states and just wanted to have some columns that kept track of the times the state were changed, but the callbacks don't seem to be working. The problems, of course, could be with my methods, I'm just not sure.

```
        aasm_state :active, :after => :activate
        aasm_state :inactive
        aasm_state :deactivated, :after => :deactivate

        aasm_event :active do
          transitions :to => :active, :from => [:inactive]
          transitions :to => :active, :from => [:deactivated]
        end

        aasm_event :deactivated do
          transitions :to => :deactivated, :from => [:active]
        end

       def activate
         activated_at = Time.now
      end  

      def deactivate
        deactivated_at = Time.now
      end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using aasm, you dont just call your activate / deactivate function on your model.

you also need to save the model, so when you do `object.activate`, after that also do `object.save` (at least that is how it was in the last version i used)

transitions seem to be written ok, so i dont think those are the problem

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 3 version of AASM, you need to apply callbacks to transition events, rather than on state. 
So you code can be -

```
    aasm_state :active

    aasm_event :active, :after => :activate do 

        transitions :to => :active, :from => [:inactive]
        transitions :to => :active, :from => [:deactivated]
    end
```